# Android: Can't change icon of "com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton"

Tags: android, facebook

Here my xml:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/signinFacebookButon"
            style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_minus"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/loginTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/loginTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/forgotPasswordTextView"
            facebook:com_facebook_login_text="@string/login_with_facebook"
            facebook:com_facebook_logout_text="" />
```

I set `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_minus"`, but icon of Facebook button not change. How I can do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 then your change to add drawable icon should have worked.

However, if you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2 (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you should add “left” in addition to “start”. like this-

**android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_minus"**

**android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_minus"**

Comment: I start on Android 6. "android:drawableLeft" and "android:drawableStart" not help. Icon not change.